# HTML Layout, menu wordings spacing error and cannot justify to the centre

Tags: css, html

I have make a html, and there has a menu on the topbar.

http://i1127.photobucket.com/albums/l622/sugarboylovephoto/ScreenShot2013-05-20at24031PM_zps2dd74d4d.png

[URL=http://s1127.photobucket.com/user/sugarboylovephoto/media/ScreenShot2013-05-20at24031PM_zps2dd74d4d.png.html][IMG]http://i1127.photobucket.com/albums/l622/sugarboylovephoto/ScreenShot2013-05-20at24031PM_zps2dd74d4d.png[/IMG][/URL]

1. The spacing between the words is too wide. For example, 'Studying Science', the space between studying and Science is too wide now. How to decrease the space? Please see the attachment
2. How to move the menu wordings centre and on top of the grey bar?

Here is the code for the menu bar

```
<div id="header">
        <div class="head-padding"></div>
        <div id="head"><img src="images/head01.png" width="1010" height="106"></div>
        <div id="nav" class="navbgimg"> 
            <a href="#about">About</a>
            <a href="#studying">Studying Science</a>
            <a href="#SSCI">About SSCI</a> 
            <a href="#highlights">Programme Highlights </a> 
            <a href="#life">Student Life</a> 
            <a href="#fun">Fun Fact</a> 
            <a href="#tips">Interview Tips</a>  </div>
            <div id="headwhite"><img src="images/head02.png" width="1010" height="20"></div>

        </div>
```

Here is the css for the menu bar

```
*{ margin: 0 auto;}


h1 {
    font-family: "source-sans-pro";
    font-size: 8pt;
}

body {
    background:#2848ad; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    font-family: "source-sans-pro",sans-serif;
    height:6078px;
}

copyright {
    margin: 0 auto; 
    font-family:"source-sans-pro"; 
    font-size: 6pt;
}


#header {
    position:fixed;
    z-index:1;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    height:160px; 
    width:100%;
}

#head {
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background:#204ab4; 
    height:106px; 
    width:1010px;
}

.navbgimg {
    background-image: url(../images/menubar01.png);
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:1010px;
    height:34px; 
}

#nav {
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 11pt;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:0px;
    height:34px; 
    width:1010px;
    word-spacing:20px;
}

#headwhite {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    height:20px; 
    width:1010px;
}

#page1 {
    position:relative;
    top:150px;
    height:390px;
    width:1010px;
    background:#00c9e5;
}
```

Comment: Can you put your code in www.jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its because your using "word-spacing"

```
word-spacing:20px;
```

inside the #nav

if i was you, i'll do this instead:

```
#nav {
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 11pt;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:0px;
    height:34px; 
    width:1010px;
    text-align: center   <---------------- require this to center the menu

}

#nav a { padding-right: 20px; display:inline-block; }
```

**EDIT**

Updated above code to support centered menu

Comment: one more thing, hope you can help. The menu wordings is too close to the blue color line. How can I move it downward, so it should be align vertical on the top of the grey bar.

Comment: try adding paddings to the #nav, or #nav a, so you have have more space. Sorry i wanna be more specific, but i copy and paste the code to my sample page but because i don't have any images, its all blue.

Answer (score 0):

```
word-spacing:20px;
```

This is your culprit. You are going to have to either create a smaller span and reset the word-spacing to normal for "Studying Science" or you are going to have to get rid of it all together and use 'margin' or 'padding' values for the individual #nav a items. (This is what I would do, for simplicity's sake.)

As for the menu moving centre and above the grey bar, you're possibly going to want to either move away from absolute positioning or change the margin-left from auto to whatever the distance between the edge of the screen the the green bar.

(Also perhaps add #nav a {display: inline-block; text-align: centre;})

Answer (score 0):

**Problem 1**

In order to increase/ decrease the space between each individual menu item in the nav bar you can use the following CSS and change the px number to get the desired effect.

`padding-left: 15px;
 padding-right: 15px;`

**Problem 2**

Additionally if you use the CSS

```
display: inline-block;
```

then the element is placed as an inline element (on the same line as adjacent content), but it behaves as a block element. This will sort out your nav bar placing.